# MacBook Pro keycap broken

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

One of the keys (keycap) of MacBook Pro keyboard broke.

It's one of the hooks that keeps it in place.

What can I do?

Comment: the upper part (the removable one)

Comment: @Buscar웃 Yeah.. That is broken I went to store and they say the they will be changing the entire keyboard.. Just one key can not be changed. Also they said it will cost me $210.

Comment: It is called key- keycap!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buy it online here http://www.powerbookmedic.com/MacBook-Pro-Keys---Individual-Key-Keycap-p-16753.html

or other places and do it your self.